# builtin for putting "split" in a pipeline?

Tags: split, gnu-coreutils

Say I want to process all the lines of `largedata.xz` with `prog1`, and `prog1` has some trouble running through all that without exhausting RAM. However, don't really need it to run on all the data as one, I'm fine with it running on every million lines of input, giving me several summaries (restarting `prog1` every million lines).

Until now I've been doing

```
$ xz -dc middlingdata.xz | while read -r; do 
    lines="${lines}"$'\n'"${REPLY}"; 
    (( i++ ))
    if [[ $i -gt 1000000 ]]; then 
        i=0
        echo "${lines}"|prog1 >$i.out
        lines=""
    fi
done
```

to avoid first doing `split` and getting a bunch of intermediate input files, but it feels like this use-case should be covered by some standard Unix tool.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out split itself handles this:

```
xz -dc mediumdata.xz | split --lines=1000000 --filter='prog1 >summary.$FILE' -
```

There was an example in `info split`